# MVC 2 RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have this code in the controller

```
public ActionResult Close(string cName)
{
    return RedirectToAction("action1", "Home",
                            new { IdsName = cName });
}
```

but the url that is being created has `%20` (space), it is being created like this

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Home/action1.mvc?IdsName = xyz%20%20asd
```

but I want the url to be this way

```
http://localhost:xxxx/Home/action1.mvc?IdsName = xyz asd
```

I want a space and not `%20`. How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%20 is the url encoded space character. Space characters are not valid characters in the uri, so the MVC framework encodes the value for you.

When your Home/Action1 method is called the value will have been url decoded (by the MVC framework) to contain the space character once more.

Comment: @user1005310 the 'expected' way is not a valid uri, if you try to tell a browser to redirect to an invalid uri it will not work.